# What is wrong with this StackView?

Tags: swift, autolayout, constraints, uistackview

what is wrong with my StackView?
This is the code:

```
class PushUpViewController: UIViewController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
            
            view.backgroundColor = .white
            setUpStackView()
        }
        
            func setUpStackView() {
            // SetUp StackView:
            stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            stackView.axis = .vertical
                stackView.alignment = .center
                stackView.distribution = .fillProportionally
            stackView.spacing = 50
            view.addSubview(stackView)
            
            // SetUp StackView Constraints:
                stackView.pin(to: view)
                stackView.setCustomSpacing(50, after: PushUpButton)
                stackView.setCustomSpacing(100, after: TimeLabel)
            
            // Set Elements to StackView:
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(TimeLabel)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(PushUpButton)
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(secondStackView)
            

       // SetUp PushUpButton:
           PushUpButton.backgroundColor = .white
           PushUpButton.setTitle("\(count)", for: .normal)
           PushUpButton.setTitleColor(.systemGray, for: .normal)
           PushUpButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 70)
           
           
           PushUpButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
           
                PushUpButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
                PushUpButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150).isActive = true
           
       
    // SetUp TimeLabel
           TimeLabel.textAlignment = .center
                   TimeLabel.text = "\(counter)"
                   TimeLabel.textColor = .black
                   TimeLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
                   self.view.addSubview(TimeLabel)
                   
                   TimeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                   
       
                TimeLabel.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300).isActive = true
                TimeLabel.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
        
      
            
            
            // SetUp SecondStackView
            secondStackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            secondStackView.axis = .horizontal
            secondStackView.alignment = .center
            secondStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
                secondStackView.spacing = 20
            
            
            // SetUp SecondStackView Constrains
                secondStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                secondStackView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor, constant: -15).isActive = true
            
            
            // Set Elements:
            secondStackView.addArrangedSubview(breakButton)
            secondStackView.addArrangedSubview(stopbutton)
            
            //SetUp BreakButton
                  breakButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
                  breakButton.setTitle("Break", for: .normal)
                  breakButton.setTitle("Start", for: .selected)
            breakButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
                  breakButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
                  breakButton.layer.cornerRadius = 12
                  breakButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
                  breakButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
//               breakButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BreakButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                  
                  
                  breakButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                  
               NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                  breakButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
                  breakButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
               ])
              
                
               
              
              // SetUp StopButton:
                  stopbutton.backgroundColor = .systemRed
                  stopbutton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
                  stopbutton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
                  stopbutton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
                  stopbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 12
                  stopbutton.layer.borderWidth = 1
                  stopbutton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
//               stopbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stopButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
                  
                  
                  stopbutton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                  
               NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                  stopbutton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150),
                  stopbutton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)
                  ])
            
            
            }
    }
```

And this is how it look:
[image]

But it should looks like this:

[image]

This is what comes in the console when I am on the StackView VC:

[image]

I have no idea what this means or what I should do to solve this problem

I do not understand StackViews... I watched a lot of yt tutorials but they are all the same and did't help me. My biggest problem is the distribution of the StackView: I don't know where the difference is

Comment: Do you want your "Time Label" to be at (or near) the top... your buttons at the bottom... and your "PushUpButton" (the large zero?) to be 300x150 and centered vertically between the them?

Comment: @DonMag I want it like at the second image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First tip: forget using `.fillProportionally` with stack views. It is almost never used ... and when it *is* used, it's used for very specific reasons.

Second tip: during development, give your UI elements contrasting background colors to make it easy to see the frames at run-time.

Third tip: Use `leadingLowerCase` for variable and function names... Use `LeadingUpperCase` for class names.

Fourth tip: group similar code together - such as setting view properties, setting constraints, etc - and include logical comments to make it easier to follow what your code is doing.

Take a look at this:

```
class PushUpViewController: UIViewController {
    
    let stackView = UIStackView()
    let secondStackView = UIStackView()
    let pushUpButton = UIButton()
    let breakButton = UIButton()
    let stopbutton = UIButton()
    let timeLabel = UILabel()
    
    var count: Int = 0
    var counter: Float = 0.0
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .white
        setUpStackView()
    }
    
    func setUpStackView() {
        
        // SetUp StackView:
        stackView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.alignment = .fill
        stackView.distribution = .fill

        // SetUp timeLabel
        timeLabel.textAlignment = .center
        timeLabel.text = "\(counter)"
        timeLabel.textColor = .black
        timeLabel.font = .boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)

        // SetUp pushUpButton:
        pushUpButton.backgroundColor = .white
        pushUpButton.setTitle("\(count)", for: .normal)
        pushUpButton.setTitleColor(.systemGray, for: .normal)
        pushUpButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 70)
        
        // SetUp secondStackView
        secondStackView.axis = .horizontal
        secondStackView.alignment = .fill
        secondStackView.distribution = .fillEqually
        secondStackView.spacing = 20
        
        //SetUp breakButton
        breakButton.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        breakButton.setTitle("Break", for: .normal)
        breakButton.setTitle("Start", for: .selected)
        breakButton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        breakButton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        breakButton.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        breakButton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        breakButton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        
        // SetUp stopButton:
        stopbutton.backgroundColor = .systemRed
        stopbutton.setTitle("Stop", for: .normal)
        stopbutton.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 20)
        stopbutton.setTitleColor(.white, for: .normal)
        stopbutton.layer.cornerRadius = 12
        stopbutton.layer.borderWidth = 1
        stopbutton.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor

        // add buttons to horizontal second stack view
        secondStackView.addArrangedSubview(breakButton)
        secondStackView.addArrangedSubview(stopbutton)

        // if we want the center PushUpButton to be 300 x 150
        //  and centered vertically
        //  we need to embed it in a clear view
        let holderView = UIView()
        
        // add PushUpButton to holderView
        holderView.addSubview(pushUpButton)

        // views added as arrangedSubviews of a stack view automatically get
        //  .translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        // but, because we're adding the PushUpButton as a subview
        //  of holderView, we need to set it here
        pushUpButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        

        // add views to stack view
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(timeLabel)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(holderView)
        stackView.addArrangedSubview(secondStackView)

        // add stackView to view
        view.addSubview(stackView)
        
        // SetUp StackView Constraints:
        //stackView.pin(to: view)
        
        // respect safe-area
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            // constrain stackview to full view (safe-area)
            
            // to bottom with Zero extra space
            stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.bottomAnchor, constant: 0.0),

            // to top with 20-pts "padding"
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            
            // and 8-pts "padding" on each side
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -8.0),
            
            // pushUpButton should be 300x150
            pushUpButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 300.0),
            pushUpButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 150.0),
            
            // pushUpButton should be centered in holderView
            pushUpButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.centerXAnchor),
            pushUpButton.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: holderView.centerYAnchor),
            
            // bottom buttons should have Height: 50
            secondStackView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50.0),
            
        ])

        // break and stop button actions
        //breakButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(BreakButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        //stopbutton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(stopButtonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)

        // during development, so we can see the layout easily
        //holderView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        //PushUpButton.backgroundColor = .green
        //TimeLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        
    }
}
```

Result on iPhone 11:

[image]

on iPhone 8:

[image]

and with background colors to help during development:

[image]

[image]

**Additional Tip:**

When learning auto layout (particularly stack views), work on your layout in Storyboard / Interface Builder. You can immediately see how it looks and what happens when changing values / properties. You can also change the **View as:** to immediately see how it looks on different devices / screen sizes. If you want to keep everything in code, once you have your layout looking the way you want, then replicate those constraints and settings in code.

Comment: Great, Thank's a lot!